# making karma testing look better(or more like rspec)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am using karma testing with grunt to do my unit testing. I am used to testing with rspec where it shows you all the tests passing and failing. 
When doing karma I am only getting this line

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (0.005 secs / 0.002 secs)

I have color set to true to make it more readable but I was wondering if there was another configuration that would list out the tests and show the passing and failing more explicitly

thanks

Comment: @RickestRick please stop making suggested edits where the total sum of your suggestion is to change "I am" to "I'm".

Comment: Will have see your Karma config. You probably need reporters. Which reporter you are using at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-mocha-reporter, although I don't like it for 500+ tests, because failed test errors are then hard to find.